# Extracting numbers from the variable in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I have a bash script which outputs some statistics on the screen for each sample number(example shown below) when I run the test.sh code.

What I am trying to do is that  to store the output in a variable  and extract the Mean value for a testNum --> 11 and 52

```
A=`./test.sh`    # I have all the output in a variable A
```

Now I need to extract the mean value of 11 which is -128 and -96 for 52 
I'm trying and thinking How I can do this

Can anyone help me in this please ?

This is the example test code : test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Valid Numbers per States:3G phones
echo testNum        N_States         Mean Value 
echo    1       10              -128 
echo    2       10      -95 
echo    3       10      -94 
echo    4       10      -94 
echo    5       10      -94 
echo    6       10      -128    
echo    7       10      -91 
echo    8       10      -94 
echo    9       10      -94     
echo    10      10      -94 
echo    11      10      -128    
echo --------------------------------------------   
echo Valid Numbers per States :4G phones        
echo testNum        N_States         Mean Value         
echo    36      10      -95 
echo    40      10      -95 
echo    44      10      -95 
echo    48      10      -95
echo    52      10      -96
echo    56      10      -95
echo    60      10      -96
echo    64      10      -96
echo    100             10      -99
echo    104             10      -97
echo    108             10      -98
echo    112             9       -98
echo    116             9       -98
echo    120             9       -99
echo    124             9       -98 
echo    128             9       -98             
echo    132             9       -98             
echo    136             9       -99             
echo    140             9       -99             
echo    144             9       -99             
echo    149             9       -98             
echo    153             9       -99 
echo    157             9       -99
echo    161             9       -99
echo    165             9       -98
echo --------------------------------------------
```

I have used the commands `echo "$x" | grep -w '^52' | cut -d' ' -f3`

But Linux on my proprietary hardware doesn't allow ^ (not sure if its version or something) .. I can run this on any bash shell..works fine, but if I run the same command, it doesn't output anything.

So I started doing some awk on it
Here temp is 128 
NF_Est is output of the script
`echo "$NF_Est" | grep -w  128 | awk '{if ($1==128)print $0}' | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3`

But this is not working if I am the "temp" values in multiple columns

Any suggestions where I am messing up (or) this can be done in a much simpler way?

Comment: backticks were replaced decades ago with a cleaner notation.  `A=$(./test.sh)`

Comment: Why are you unable to use `^`? Does the computer crash or catch fire, or do you get a syntax error, or do you not have a keyboard with this symbol? Even if the system is proprietary, it almost certainly has a `^` character.

Comment: @tripleee U should have clearly read that..."" I can run this on any bash shell..works fine, but if I run the same command, it doesn't output anything ""

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell .. I will keep that in mind. I started shell scripting like in 3 days ago .. good to know that the backticks were replaced.. I will use (./test.sh) from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want `awk` for this:

```
$ ./test.sh | awk '$1==11{print $3}'
-128
$ ./test.sh | awk '$1==52{print $3}'
-96
```

If you want to extract the value from `$A` instead of running the script, just do: `echo "$A" | awk ...`

Comment: Thanks @William ..this works great. I have these numbers 11 and 52 as a variable.. Do you by chance know what I am doing wrong here .. I am storing 11 and 52 in a $temp variable                                                                                                                                     ``` echo "$A" | awk -v myvar="$temp" 'BEGIN {if ($1 eq  myvar) print $3}' ```                                      why doing this wouldn't give me any output (as technically I am doing the same )

Comment: or even this ..   ``` echo "$A" | awk -v myvar="$temp" '$1==myvar {print $3}' ```

Comment: @Saira You don't want to put the check in a BEGIN clause.  You want it to run on each line of input.  eg, `echo "$A" | awk '$1 == k { print $3 }' k="$temp"`

Comment: Thanks, @William  . I understood where I am going wrong. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` and `cut` to extract the information:

```
echo "$x" | grep -w '^11' | cut -d' ' -f3
echo "$x" | grep -w '^52' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

`grep` filters its input, outputting only lines that match the given pattern. `^` matches at the beginning of line. `-w` means "match whole words", without it, it would also output the lines **11**2 and **11**6.

`cut` extracts columns from its intput. `-d` specifies the delimiter, a space in this case, and `-f` says which columns to extract.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ... Really appreciate it. But I have some issued with it as I am running this on a Linux system on proprietary hardware. For some reason, I cannot use '^' operator in the grep. I tried the following ```                                     
       echo "$Out_Var" | grep -w '128' | awk -v cx=$temp '{if ($1==cx) print }'      ```       $temp is 128 , the number to be searched.... I have added my answer edit part of question.. Is there any way I can get away with awk ?